# How does pub/sub in firebase cloud function work?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cron, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

I'm building a web application about working schedule management with firebase.
The flow is :

-Creation of template of shift schedule:

```
template = {
    schedule : [
      {
        day : 'Monday',
        work_time : '10am-6pm'
      },
      {
        day : 'Tuesday',
        work_time : '8am-3pm'
      }
    ],
    from_date : '2021/01/25',
    to_date : '2021/05/25'
  }
```

-Creation of shift on user:
Add template to user's shift or edit template

so basically, i need to pass the template data of user to subscribe to cloud scheduler to add to user's shift everyday within the date range.

```
shift = {
   user_id : 'user_id',
   day : 'Monday',
   work_date : '2021/01/25',
   work_time : '10am-6pm',
  }
 // on the next day auto create
 shift = {
   user_id : 'user_id',
   day : 'Tuesday',
   work_date : '2021/01/26',
   work_time : '8am-3pm'
  }
```

-I need to unsubscribe the scheduler when editing template on user's shift.

-In the template creation, there's a button to stop creating shift on all users who have that template.

Do i make any sense?
Please help with my use case. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common in some use cases to add template/initial data to a database every midnight (or anytime depending on use case) so that can be updated or listed somewhere.

> I need to unsubscribe the scheduler when editing template on each user's shift.

> I also need to unsubscribe all related user's scheduler when click stop creating button on template creation.

There's no direct way to do anything like that. When a user starts editing their shift you would have to store that in a database first. In your scheduled function you can check (from database) if a task is being edited. If yes, then skip it and proceed with others.

Also what do you mean by *"all related user's scheduler"*? Ideally you will have a single cloud function that will process all users and not a dedicated pub/sub topic for every users. You just follow the same way as in first case, if a user has clicked that *stop button* then store that in database and don't process that user whenever your function runs.

Comment: i meant in the template creation, there's a button to stop creating shift on all users who have that template.

Comment: @TorSenghok do you have any Firestore documents for those templates so it's easier for you to explain? You can add a field maybe storing `false` in those users' documents in database and then not create templates for them?

Comment: i think when the button is clicked, it will basically stop auto adding template data to every user's shift who has that template. so my use case is Many pubs to One sub, right? thus there's no way i can unsubscribe it.

Comment: @TorSenghok what I meant was, ideally you would run a single Cloud function for all the user and not a separate cloud function for each user. let's say you have a collection in Firestore for users where each doc will have a field "stopped". This field must be set to true if the user has clicked stop button else set it to false. When your scheduled cloud function runs you will check for users whose `stopped` field is set to false i.e. they have not clicked stop button. Now add templates for those users only

Comment: i'm really new to this pub/sub. can you please fill me in on how to pass data from client to cloud function scheduler ?

Comment: @TorSenghok you don't pass data to the function.  You add it in database. You got Discord by chance? It'll be easier to discuss there as originall question is answered.

Comment: i finally understand you. :) so i just need to add data to firestore then have one scheduler function to read and write all new data.

Comment: @H.O.K exactly. This way you are handling all users at cost of single cloud functions. Firestore queries are simple too `.where("hasStopped", "==", false)` will fetch all users who have not clicked the stop button. Fetch and process them all in the function using loops and batch writes.